# /public still appears in some URLs but not others after updating .htaccess file

Tags: laravel, .htaccess

I've updated my `.htaccess` in public_html root directory to try to remove `/public` from the URL

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

It works for some URLs but not others. I've cleared server & browser cache. Still no improvement.

I'm working with `Laravel 5.7, PHP 7`

Any help appreciated. If more info needed let me know and I'll do my best to provide it.

Cheers

Comment: If you can, you should really try to avoid having the web root point to your laravel project folder to avoid all of the issues that could arise from exposing private data.  Then you wouldn't have to worry about this rule.  Have the web server point to public and be done with it.

Answer (score 0):

Edit your .htaccess with this code. it might help

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ ^$1 [N]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (\.\w+$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ server.php

</IfModule>
```